# What's waking my laptop up?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, lid

Sometimes, but not always, my laptop running 14.04 wakes up a few seconds after I shut the lid.

How do I diagnose what's going on here? I want it to be suspended when the lid closes and stay suspended until the lid is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your settings gui, click on "power" and make sure your power settings,when closing the lid, are set to your liking.

Comment: I use xmonad, not Unity or GNOME. I'm not sure how to get to a power settings gui.

Comment: do you have a settings option on your task bar? if not search your comp for "system settings". and power should be an option in there. don't use terminal for easier use.

Comment: Cory, I only use the terminal. I'd like to actually understand what's going on under the hood. Is there a way to get ACPI to provide details on what's waking the system up?