# What process / event is waking up my laptop?

Tags: suspend, 22.04

This question is similar to this one [What's waking my laptop up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574865/whats-waking-my-laptop-up), but for Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 9310. It follows on from this question: [Intermittent - Dell XPS 9310, 22.04 does not turn off with lid closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407426/intermittent-dell-xps-9310-22-04-does-not-turn-off-with-lid-closed)

I've now established that the laptop is waking up with the lid closed (`cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state`). The laptop basically goes into cycles of sleeping/waking up. For example, the 'pre-sleep' times are like this:

```
Tue  5 Jul 05:31:17 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:32:07 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:32:56 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:33:45 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:34:35 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:35:24 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:36:13 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:37:03 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:37:52 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:38:42 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:39:31 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:40:20 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:41:10 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:41:59 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:42:49 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:43:38 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:44:27 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:45:17 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:46:06 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:46:56 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:47:45 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:48:34 BST 2022
Tue  5 Jul 05:49:24 BST 2022
```

How can I diagnose the problem? It is intermittent: When I reboot, the sleep works. But over time, something 'happens' to the system, that stops it from going to sleep properly.

Comment: The same issue occurs without the lid closed. I.e., after the laptop has been on for some time, going to sleep for power save (lid open) also doesn't work. Laptop goes to sleep, but wakes up again in cycles.

Comment: I'm on 22.04.1 now, but the problem still occurs.